# Изменение ID в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Имеюстся рандомные ID номера в таблице, как с помощью запроса изменить значения ID, с рандомных на порядковые 1,2,3 и так далее?

Comment: `set @n=0; update t1 set id=(@n:=@n+1);`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я так понял этот запрос изменить id=0 на id=1, но у меня куча рандомных ID, как мне это поможет установить порядок.

Comment: [Что-такое-Ошибка-x-y-или-xy-problem](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/)

Comment: нет он поменякт у всех подряд. ща сделаю пример

Comment: @AlexeyAl http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2023b/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ, предложенный [splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440324/#comment462357_440324):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2023b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (id int);
insert into t1 values
(1),
(2),
(4),
(7);

set @n=0;
update t1 set id=(@n:=@n+1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2023b/1/0)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
```